# Problem of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $u: ~\mathbb R\to \mathbb R.$

Let $p\in(1,\infty).$

Let $f(x)=|x|^{p-2}x$ and $g(x)=x^{p-1}$.

We know that $f$ is continuous if and only if $g$ is continuous.

Now suppose $f\circ u$ is continuous.

Can we conclude that $g\circ u$ is continuous?

---

**Attempt:** I have proved the case that $p$ is integer. However, when $p$ involves decimals, the situation becomes rather difficult and we have to introduce complex numbers into our problem. Now the problem reduces to the case that $p$ is not integer. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

---

**Edit:** The case that $p$ involves decimals is indeed more sophisticated. The reason is that, for $x<0$, $f(x)$ is always a real number. However, $$g(x)=(-x)^{p-1} e^{(p-1)i\pi},$$ which has an imaginary part. If $p$ is not integer, then $g(x)\in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$.